# Stimulsoft exporting pdf with only squares

Tags: c#, azure, pdf, report, stimulsoft

i'm working with Stimulsoft in C# WebAPI running on Azure App Service. When i export my report as PDF all the text is rendered as squares, like this

[image]

when export as HTML the report is correct. Locally or in a Virtual Machine in Azure the pdf file is correct, the problem occurs only on Azure App Service.

this is the code i use to export pdf. The font i use is Arial, some parts have bold or italic.

```
var settings = new StiPdfExportSettings() { ImageQuality = 1.0f, ImageResolution = 300, EmbeddedFonts = true, StandardPdfFonts = true };

                report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Pdf, ms, settings);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem changing the pdf settings to export like this

```
var settings = new StiPdfExportSettings() { ImageQuality = 1.0f, ImageResolution = 300, EmbeddedFonts = false, UseUnicode = false, StandardPdfFonts = true };
```

this works only with StandardPdfFonts = true and EmbeddedFonts = false, only UseUnicode = false doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The PDF export needs get access to font files that are used in a report. Stimulsoft report engine uses GDI+ to get access to necessary information about the fonts.

Azure Web Sites have restrictions a restriction on access to GDI+.

The one way out is to use [Standard PDF fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29).

Or you could prepare necessary fonts for PDF export on your local machine. In this case, you don't need the access to GDI+ functions.

How it works:

- using [the FontInfoCreator utility](https://github.com/stimulsoft/FontInfoCreator), you create font files (*.fiz)
- in the init part of your application load these files to the font store.

Sample code:

```
Stimulsoft.Report.Export.FontsInfoStore.LoadFontInfoToStore("Arial", @"fontstore\Arial.fiz");
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue with fonts is caused by the Azure Web Sites service's limitation: it has access to the limited set of fonts only and is not [providing access](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7335161-support-html-to-pdf-rendering) ([confirmed by another MS employee too](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-us/70fb49fa-3cfa-4c37-a99b-1b63c4001eac/font-types-used-on-azure-website-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)) to GDI+ subsystem device context that is required for fonts rendering.

You may also expect `General GDI+ error` occured if you try to manipulate fonts or their parameters.

The suggested solutions are

- Use [SQL Server Reporting Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/pdf-generation-and-loading-file-based-certificates-in-azure-websites/)
- Host your website on [virtual Windows machine](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/)